# Is it possible to use my own settings for the hardware clock on pigpio?

Tags: pigpio

I would like to use my own clock settings (integer, fractional, and mash) instead on the one that is autogenerated by the function gpioHardwareClock.  Is it possible to do that with pigpio ?

If not what how do i modify the library so that i can do so ? I know the library calls this function to start the clock but i have no way of accessing it?

```
static void initHWClk
   (int clkCtl, int clkDiv, int clkSrc, int divI, int divF, int MASH)
{
   DBG(DBG_INTERNAL, "ctl=%d div=%d src=%d /I=%d /f=%d M=%d",
      clkCtl, clkDiv, clkSrc, divI, divF, MASH);

   /* kill the clock if busy, anything else isn't reliable */

   if (clkReg[clkCtl] & CLK_CTL_BUSY)
   {
      do
      {
         clkReg[clkCtl] = BCM_PASSWD | CLK_CTL_KILL;
      }
      while (clkReg[clkCtl] & CLK_CTL_BUSY);
   }

   clkReg[clkDiv] = (BCM_PASSWD | CLK_DIV_DIVI(divI) | CLK_DIV_DIVF(divF));

   usleep(10);

   clkReg[clkCtl] = (BCM_PASSWD | CLK_CTL_MASH(MASH) | CLK_CTL_SRC(clkSrc));

   usleep(10);

   clkReg[clkCtl] |= (BCM_PASSWD | CLK_CTL_ENAB);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing stopping you from making a change to your local copy of the source code, recompiling, and relinking.

Make the changes in the pigpio source directory (to pigpio.c) and then type `make` followed by `sudo make install`.

Comment: that function is already at pigpio.c, but im getting an error that initHWClk is undefined when compiling.

Comment: Please add the compiler output to your question.